XSLT 3.0 Processing JSON: improving a functions-based solution
I took @Michael Kay's comment at How to convert JSON to XML using XSLT? to heart when he said:

XSLT 3.0 isn't actually that good at processing JSON using template
rules: it can be done, but it isn't very convenient. It's usually more
convenient to use functions.

Given a slightly more than just trivial JSON as input, namely:
{
  "name": "Alice",
  "age": 30,
  "children": [
    {"name": "Charlie", "age": 5},
    {"name": "Daisy", "age": 3}
   ]
}

I wanted to

extract the children
process them by raising their ages by 10 respectively
and create a result XML with derived element- and attribute-names.

The XML result should be:
<olderChildren>
    <child name="Charlie" age="15"/>
    <child name="Daisy" age="13"/>
</olderChildren>

To compare the newer function-based approach with the traditional template-based approach I created 2 stylesheets to compare their metrics side by side.
This is the function-based stylesheet:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
                xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
                exclude-result-prefixes="map array">
                
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="json-data">
    {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": 30,
        "children": [
            {"name": "Charlie", "age": 5},
            {"name": "Daisy", "age": 3}
        ]
    }
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="parsed-json" select="parse-json($json-data)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="map:get($parsed-json, 'children')"/>       <!-- Extract children array -->
        <xsl:variable name="older-children" as="array(*)" select="array:for-each($children, function($child) {map:put($child, 'age', map:get($child, 'age') + 10)})"/> <!-- Create array of children whose age is raised by 10 years-->
        <xsl:element name="olderChildren"><!-- Output result XML -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$older-children?*">
                <xsl:element name="child">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name" select="map:get(., 'name')"/>
                    <xsl:attribute name="age" select="map:get(., 'age')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

and this is the template-based stylesheet:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="fn">
                
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="json">
    {
        "name": "Alice",
        "age": 30,
        "children": [
            {"name": "Charlie", "age": 5},
            {"name": "Daisy", "age": 3}
        ]
    }
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:variable name="XMLfromJSON" select="json-to-xml($json)"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$XMLfromJSON/fn:map/fn:array"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'children']">
        <xsl:element name="{fn:concat('older',fn:upper-case(fn:substring(@key,1,1)),fn:substring(@key,2))}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'children']/fn:map">
        <xsl:element name="{fn:substring(../@key,1,5)}">
            <xsl:attribute name="{./fn:string/@key}" select="./fn:string"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="{./fn:number/@key}" select="./fn:number + 10"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

How can I convert my functional solution to have the structure of the template-based solution, i.e. with apply-templates while maintaining the possibility to derive result XML element names with expressions the ways I did in the template-based solution (i.e. with substring() etc.)?
One more technical background question: In the function-based solution the contents of <xsl:variable name="older-children" /> was obviously created by creating a deep copy of <xsl:variable name="children"> before processing the new copy (by adding 10 to the ages within all child-maps). One can see that when replacing <xsl:for-each select="$older-children?*"> with <xsl:for-each select="$children?*"> during XML result generation. Then the result is:
<olderChildren>
    <child name="Charlie" age="5"/>
    <child name="Daisy" age="3"/>
</olderChildren>

, i.e. the ages are the original values.
The select-expression of <xsl:variable name="older-children" /> however seems to reference the maps inside the $children-variable, at least when looking at the code at face-value: That function($child) which is called on every $child of that iteration seems to overwrite field 'age' in that current $child of $children, NOT a newly created deep copy of $children (select="array:for-each($children, function($child) {map:put($child, 'age', map:get($child, 'age') + 10)}). Where in the XSLT 3.0 spec does it say that such a deep copy is what is happening?

Please have a look at the [tour] and [ask] - A question should focus on one programming-related problem at the time. Furthermore, the questions you are asking will lead to opinionated answers, making your question(s) off-topic.

Also in terms of elegance, be aware that both the Saxon command line as well as its API allow you to pass in any XDM item (i.e. in case of JSON an XDM map or XDM array) directly as the initial match selection and/or global context item (e.g. -json:sample.json instead of -s:sample.xml on the command line). Your approach with processing some (dummy?) XML input with <xsl:template match="/"> to then parse a JSON string parameter seems a bit convoluted.

I would have loved to engage on this one, but the person who closed it is correct; it's rather too discursive for StackOverflow. It's the sort of discussion that works better on the xsl-list hosted by mulberrytech.com But first: have you read my 2016 paper at https://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmlprague-2016mhk.pdf and its 2024 follow-up at https://www.saxonica.com/papers/xmlprague-2024mhk.pdf ?

@MichaelKay Maybe OP can move this to the discusssions then

@MichaelKay I have revised the question now only focussing on improving the function-based solution. I would love for you to engage now, after it is open again, that is.
I have not read your 2024 paper, since I must find solutions with XSLT 3.0 and Altova XMLSpy 2024 where for the life of me I can't even find how to set the xsl:initial-template. As for the 2016 paper, I struggled with piecing it together as a set of files. I wasn't sure how to create the maps-and-arrays.xsl or the <xsl:function name="jlib:apply-templates"> for example. Is there a downloadable set of files for this paper?

@MartinHonnen Yes I agree having to use a dummy XML file just to start processing JSON is a workaround and a bad one at that. I need self-contained stylesheets with the intput data as a string inside of it for a seminar-like situation. Also I have to use Altova XMLSpy 2024 where I can't seem to find how to pass the xsl:initial-template to the processor.

Maps in XPath 3.1/XDM 3.1/XSLT 3.0 are immutable so any map:put never manipulates the original map, rather it returns a new map with the changed property.
https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#map-functions:

As with all other values, the functions in this specification treat
maps as immutable. For example, the map:remove function returns a map
that differs from the supplied map by the omission (typically) of one
entry, but the supplied map is not changed by the operation. Two calls
on map:remove with the same arguments return maps that are
indistinguishable from each other; there is no way of asking whether
these are "the same map".

As for achieving the wanted output
<olderChildren>
    <child name="Charlie" age="15"/>
    <child name="Daisy" age="13"/>
</olderChildren>

with XSLT 3 processing the JSON with parse-json, I would do e.g.
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
                xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
                exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
                
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:param name="json-data">
  {
      "name": "Alice",
      "age": 30,
      "children": [
          {"name": "Charlie", "age": 5},
          {"name": "Daisy", "age": 3}
      ]
  }
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="parsed-json" select="parse-json($json-data)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <olderChildren>
      <xsl:for-each select="$parsed-json?children?*!map:put(., 'age', ?age + 10)">
        <child name="{?name}" age="{?age}"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </olderChildren>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Online fiddle.

Thank you, that clears it up. Thanks also for the extra effort to link to the spec and providing the quote!

the ages are the original values. The select-expression of <xsl:variable name="older-children" /> however seems to reference the maps inside the $children-variable, at least when looking at the code at face-value:
